# Why isn't this CSS margin 0 applied?

Tags: html, css, sass, margin

I set `<body>` to `margin: 0;` yet it leaves 8px of space. How can I clear this white space?

The navbar should be touching the side and the top of the page. `<img />` and `<h1>` should be touching the side of the navbar:

[image]

CSS (Sass) :

```
// Imported fonts:
@font-face {
  src: url(fonts/MajorMonoDisplay-Regular.ttf);
  font-family: MojoMono;
}

//Color Variables:
$colors: (
  backGroundColor: #c1a5c6,
  purpleBorder: #511a59,
  greyFont: #373647,
  navButtonColor: #ea7985,
  redButtonBorder: #b53f4b,
);

//Body:
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: MojoMono;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: map-get($color, greyFont);
}

img {
  border: solid 4px map-get($color, purpleBorder);
}

//Navbar:
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 10px $darkAccentColor;
}

.nav img {
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
.nav h1 {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: map-get($color, greyFont);
  margin: 0px;
}
.nav button {
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: map-get($color, navButtonColor);
  color: map-get($color, greyFont);
  border: solid 4px map-get($color, redButtonBorder);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title>Hidden Expressions</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>

    <script defer src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The React element:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './NavBar';

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="header">
          <h1>Our Story</h1>
          <img src="https://for.eharmony.com/dating-advice/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dating-a-hairdresser.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I 'inspect' in browser it does not show that I set the margin to 0. But when I set it to 0 in the browser it looks like it should.

Browser inspection:

[image]

After editing in browser:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Combine:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Into:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Put it at the very top of your CSS document, directly under the first line, the charset line:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body, html {
....
```

Also, you do not need to set a class for `<div class="main">`. You can simply use `<main></main>` and style it on your CSS document as `main { background-color: none; }` (notice that there is no `.` before the style for main in your CSS. It is one of the Semantic Elements in HTML5, so it is treated the same way `body` is.

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML have its own margins and padding for each element. If you want make margin 0, you need to make css reset for only one element, for example body or you can make css reset for all elements(it's better). I use css reset of eric mayers. Here it is.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

You can put it in the begging of your css file. Or create another css file. And link him before your style. Here is ready code with reset and your code

```
//css reset
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
// Imported fonts:
@font-face {
  src: url(fonts/MajorMonoDisplay-Regular.ttf);
  font-family: MojoMono;
}

//Color Variables:
$colors: (
  backGroundColor: #c1a5c6,
  purpleBorder: #511a59,
  greyFont: #373647,
  navButtonColor: #ea7985,
  redButtonBorder: #b53f4b,
);



//Body:

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: MojoMono;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: map-get($color, greyFont);
}

img {
  border: solid 4px map-get($color, purpleBorder);
}

//Navbar:
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 10px $darkAccentColor;
}

.nav img {
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
.nav h1 {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: map-get($color, greyFont);
  margin: 0px;
}
.nav button {
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: map-get($color, navButtonColor);
  color: map-get($color, greyFont);
  border: solid 4px map-get($color, redButtonBorder);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Using !important is not recommended. You will have not valid code.

Comment: Tried pasting it in above and still not working, any thoughts on why? Thanks!

Comment: Try to add reset css to your React element, that you show in your message. You must add reset css to main html file, in which you connect another part of the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify margin property to margin : 0 !important;
It's a quick fix, I can explain in detail too.

Comment: tried this but doesn't seem to make a difference. thoughts on why? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just add !important with the margin:0 that you have used inside the body. Like--

```css
body{
margin:0 !important;
}
```